# Html + Css page not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to html I created a html page and looks good but don't know why the page is not responsive on mobile

here is my html and css code please someone help me

```css
.link-menu {
    color: black;
}

.topbar-profile-photo {
    width: 1.5em; 
    height: 1.5em; 
    position: relative;
}

.story-profile-photo {
    width: 56px; 
    height: 56px; 
    position: relative; 
    border-width: 2px !important;
}

.post-profile-photo {
    width: 46px; 
    height: 46px; 
    position: relative; 
    border-width: 2px !important;
}

.sidenav-profile-photo {
    width: 56px; 
    height: 56px; 
    position: relative; 
}

.comment-box {
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.input-post {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-ig {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #89216b;
    font-weight: 600;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    outline: none !important;
}

.btn-ig:hover,
.btn-ig:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #89216 !important;
}

.profile-info {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.profile-info-username {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.sugest-profile-photo {
    width: 46px; 
    height: 46px;  
    position: relative;
}

.sugest-username {
    font-size: 14px
}

.btn-group button {
  background-color: white; /* Green background */
  border: solid #d1cfcf; /* Grey border */
  border-width: 1px; /* Border width */
  color: #89216b; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d3d6f2df1f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center col-9">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="assets/images/ig-logo.png" alt="" loading="lazy">
                    </a>
                    <div>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-4">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">

                        <!-- START OF STORIES -->
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-start">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                       
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END OF STORIES -->

                        <!-- START OF POSTS -->
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4 mb-4">

                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header p-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                                        <div
                                            class="rounded-circle overflow-hidden d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border border-danger post-profile-photo mr-3">
                                            <img src="assets/images/profiles/profile-1.jpg" alt="..."
                                                style="transform: scale(1.5); width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0;">
                                        </div>
                                        <figure>
                                            <span class="font-weight-bold">Outfitters</span>
                                            <figcaption>08/03/2021</figcaption>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body p-0">
                                    <p class="d-block mb-1" style="margin: 10px;">Lil drone shot I got a while back but never posted.</p>
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
                                        <img class="embed-responsive-item" src="assets/images/posts/post-1.jpg" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
                                      
                                      <button style="width:33.3%">Like</button>
                                      <button style="width:33.3%">Comment</button>
                                      <button style="width:33.3%">Share</button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pb-2">
                                        <strong class="d-block">365 likes</strong>
                                        <strong class="d-block">Outfitters</strong>
                                        
                                        <button class="btn p-0">
                                            <span class="text-muted">View all 100 comments</span>
                                        </button>

                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <strong class="d-block">Usama</strong>
                                                <span>❤️</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <strong class="d-block">Saqib</strong>
                                                <span>Hi</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <small class="text-muted">4 HOURS AGO</small>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="position-relative comment-box">
                                        <form>
                                            <input class="w-100 border-0 p-3 input-post" placeholder="Add a comment...">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary position-absolute btn-ig">Post</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- END OF POSTS -->
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>

<footer>
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS doesn't make a page responsive in any environment, because you've used absolute units to define the layout.

Comment: you need to make css specific to screen size using @media querires for your page to be responsive to different devises.

Comment: @Teemu any link or any help what to do is css

Comment: HTML/CSS is by default responsive. Using fixed width/height makes it unresponsive

Comment: You should learn css @media querires. bellow this link can help you. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Take a look at [Sizing items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS) and [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) and when you're using Bootstrap, reading [the manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/) is also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that problem in using `col-9` and `col-8` those you apply for divs inside `div.container`

`col-9` and `col-8` classes have max-width and flex properties those limit the width.

Just remove them, and it should help with mobile view, but you have to tweak your CSS styles a little bit more,  depends what you want to achieve to desktop and tablet screens.